# Instantaneous speed

Tags: geometry

Hello people of the internet. Today i did an attempt to solve the instantaneous speed at point B when it rises vertically 0,14 radians or 8 degrees per minute. Point A is 150 meters away from where point B started and when point B reaches 0,14 radians or 8 degrees per minute point B han an angle of 45 degrees og pi/4 from the point A. I did some calculations and ended up with  the note on the picture. Do you think i have done somthing wrong, or do you belive this is correct?

[image]

Comment: 0,000000144m according to what i calcalated

Comment: If im correct then that should be 0,00000000233 radians / microsecond. So it will be 0,00000000233 radians higher then before.

Comment: So by "new height" you mean pi/4 + 0,00000000233? Which is 0,7853981657 radians?

Answer (score 1):

We have the relation $\tan\theta=\frac yx$, where $y$ is the side opposite $A$, and $x$ is the side opposite $B$. Our goal in this problem is to find $dy/dt$ when $x=150\text{ m}$, $\theta=\pi/4\text{ rad}$ and $d\theta/dt=0.14\text{ rad/min}$.

Solving these types of problems are known as related rates problems.

Note that when solving related rates problems, we generally take the derivative of the relationship, and then plug in values; however, we are allowed to plug in values before taking the derivative if the value is constant with respect to $t$. Notice that $x=150$ is constant (that is, as time goes on, this distance does not change), so our relation is $\tan\theta=\frac y{150}$

Now, if we differentiate both sides with respect to time $t$, we get

\begin{align*}
\sec^2\theta\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{150}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}&\implies \sec^2(\pi/4)\cdot0.14=\frac1{150}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\\
&\implies 0.28=\frac{1}{150}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\\
&\implies \frac{dy}{dt}=42
\end{align*}

So the vertical instantaneous speed of $B$ at that moment is $42\text{ m/min}$.